# For continuous $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ with finite $a = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ the IVT applies

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I hope the title is not misleading. Let me refine:

> Let $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that a *finite* $\displaystyle a= \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ exists. Show that for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ strictly between $f(0)$ and $a$ we can find $x$ such that $f(x) = c$

---

**My approach**: My main problem is that I don't think that I can naively apply the intermediate value theorem to the problem above, because the theorem strictly requires a closed interval of the form $I = [a,b]$, so in order to establish the statement I came up with the following 'work around'.

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary such that $f(0) < c < a = \lim_{x \to + \infty} f(x)(< \infty)$

Introduce $g: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x) =f(x)-c$. Clearly $g$ is continuous on the semi open interval $[0, \infty)$  (composition of continuous functions)  and we have $g(0)=f(0)-c <0$. We also have $$\lim_{x \to + \infty} g(x) = a-c >0 \tag{*} $$
Translating statement (*) into its definition that means $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists S \in \mathbb{R} : |g(x)-(a-c)|< \epsilon, \text{ for all } x \in [0, \infty) \text{ with } x >S  \tag{1}$$
The last part of the definition (1) above can be read as for all $x \in (S, \infty)$. My idea now was to choose $x' \in (S, \infty)$ because that $x'$ should still be 'good enough' to follow the above criteria (1). So that would lead me to $$ g(x')=a-c >0$$
and now I could apply the intermediate value theorem on the closed interval $[0, x']$. i.e. find $x^* \in [0, x']$ such that $g(x)=0 \implies f(x^*)=c$ which gives the desired surjectivity.

Is this correct or am I overthinking the problem to an extend where the solution might be much simpler?

Comment: The idea is correct, by picking the right end of the bounded interval large enough, we guarantee that the function value there is close enough to $a$ to be sure that it exceeds $c$. Not sure if the detour to $g$ is needed though - do you have the IVT only available for sign changes and zeroes of fucntions?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @HagenvonEitzen, I appreciate it. I do not only have the IVT for sign changes and/or zeros. But this was how the statement was most obvious to me. I will try to make things more 'tidy' without the detour to $g$.

Comment: Just as inspiratoin, an alternative approach: Let $h(x)=\begin{cases}f(\frac1{1-x}-1)&\text{for $0\le x<1$}\\a&\text{for $x=1$}\end{cases}$. Argue that $h$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and apply the IVT to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, the effort commendable, and except for the detail that, as far as I see, we don't have $f(x')=a-c>0$ but merely $f(x')>0$, which is also sufficient, your proof will work.

However, you could also do that a lot simpler.

Note that we have $c<a \iff \exists \varepsilon>0: c<a-\varepsilon$, and (continuity of $f$) there is a $t$ such that $f(x)\in (a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$, hence $f(x)>c\quad \forall x\geq t$.

Now, if you take a look at the closed interval $[0,t]$, you can directly apply the IVT.